# UITableView Multi Selection's selected checkmark not remains checked

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4.2

I have two `UITableView` in my application.
One is for Category and Second is for SubCategory.
On the basis of selected Category SubCategory `UITableView`, data will change, and SubCategory `UITableView` have multi-selection functionality, till this my application is working fine.

Now the problem is when I am on category `UITableView` and click on suppose Category cell it will redirect to the various subCategory, On that screen, I have selected multiple choices and click on back button appear on top, and when I click again on Category tab my selection(Checkmark) is disappearing.

I want my checkmark to be selected as long as I manually set them as unchecked.

How can I implement that thing?

Sample screenshot of my application attached below.

[image: Category TableView]

[image: Appear this screen when I click on Category tab]

[image: Check mark disappear when clicking on the back button and again click in Category cell]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tblSubCategory.cellForRow(at: indexPath)

    if cell!.isSelected
    {
        cell!.isSelected = false
        if cell!.accessoryType == UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
        {
            if strCategoryData == "Category" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
                let objectForCell = arrSubCategoryData[indexPath.row]
                arrSelectedCetegoryIndex.append(objectForCell)
                let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
                defaults.set(arrSelectedCetegoryIndex, forKey: "categoryKey")
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Brand" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
                let objectForCell = arrSubCategoryData[indexPath.row]
                arrSelectedBrandIndex.append(objectForCell)
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Color" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
                let objectForCell = arrSubCategoryData[indexPath.row]
                arrSelectedColorIndex.append(objectForCell)
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Size" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark
                let objectForCell = arrSubCategoryData[indexPath.row]
                arrSelectedSizeIndex.append(objectForCell)
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if strCategoryData == "Category" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
                let selectedIndex = (tblSubCategory.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
                let selectedIndexValue = arrSubCategoryData[selectedIndex]
                print(selectedIndexValue)
                let index = arrSelectedCetegoryIndex.firstIndex(of: selectedIndexValue)!
                arrSelectedCetegoryIndex.remove(at: index)
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Brand" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
                let selectedIndex = (tblSubCategory.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
                let selectedIndexValue = arrSubCategoryData[selectedIndex]
                print(selectedIndexValue)
                let index = arrSelectedBrandIndex.firstIndex(of: selectedIndexValue)!
                arrSelectedBrandIndex.remove(at: index)
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Color" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
                let selectedIndex = (tblSubCategory.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
                let selectedIndexValue = arrSubCategoryData[selectedIndex]
                print(selectedIndexValue)
                let index = arrSelectedColorIndex.firstIndex(of: selectedIndexValue)!
                arrSelectedColorIndex.remove(at: index)
            }
            else if strCategoryData == "Size" {
                cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
                let selectedIndex = (tblSubCategory.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row)!
                let selectedIndexValue = arrSubCategoryData[selectedIndex]
                print(selectedIndexValue)
                let index = arrSelectedSizeIndex.firstIndex(of: selectedIndexValue)!
                arrSelectedSizeIndex.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share you some code how you are managing all this. i think you have to manage that by array by storing selected values.

Comment: right. when subcategory cell is selected each time i append its value to the array

Comment: @TejasPatel - are you checking  that selected values array in `cellForRowAt` method?

Comment: share code of `cellForRowAt indexPath` method

Comment: @UdayBabariya updated my question with didselectrowatindex path method code

Comment: You need to maintain the selection data somewhere in your `subCategory` model.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably performing a segue to go to the sub category view controller, and every time you perform this segue, tableview delegate and datasource methods are called again and cells are initialized all over again.

For you to show your cells checked you are going to need to save the checked values in the Categories view controller and pass them to the SubCategory View Controller and set the checked values in your cellForRowAtIndexpath method.

Here is an example on how to implement that:

```
class CategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    var checkedValues = [[Bool]]()
    var indexSelected = -1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // your code here
        checkedValues.append(contentsOf: repeatElement([], count: yourCategArray.count))


    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // your code here
        indexSelected = indexPath.row
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourSegueIdentifierHere", sender: self)
    }    


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        (segue.destination as! SubCategoryViewController).parentCategoryVC = self

    }

}
```

Now for the other View Controller:

```
class SubCategoryViewController: UIViewController {

    var parentCategoryVC = CategoryViewController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected].count == 0 {
            parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected].append(contentsOf: repeatElement(false, count: yourSubCategArray.count))

        }

        // your code here

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return yourSubCategArray.count
   }





    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell...

        if parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected][indexPath.row] { cell.accessoryType = .checkmark } else { cell.accessoryType = .none }

        // your code here

        return cell

    }


        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // your code 
            parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected][indexPath.row] = !parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected][indexPath.row]
            tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPath, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.none)

       }
}
```

For any additional clarification feel free to ask

Comment: if parentCategoryVC.checkedValues[parentCategoryVC.indexSelected].count == 0 { ///// throws error here (Index out of range)

Comment: Let me check and fix it.

Comment: Try it now. Sorry for the mistake but I am unable to test it right now

Answer (score 0):

You need to create one Int type array and then append value on click if not in array and if already exist so you need to remove from array and set checkmark in cellForRowAt method.

**Please See complete code**

```swift
import UIKit

class testViewController: UIViewController {

    
    var selectedRows: [Int] = []
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}

extension testViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")!
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Welcome " + (indexPath.row+1).description
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        cell.accessoryType = selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) ? .checkmark : .none
        return cell
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 50
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if self.selectedRows.contains(indexPath.row) {
            
            if let index = self.selectedRows.firstIndex(of: indexPath.row) {
                self.selectedRows.remove(at: index)
            }
        } else {
            self.selectedRows.append(indexPath.row)
        }
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: checkmark is showing properly when i select cells but it won't appear when i go back and come again in same category

Comment: Oh thank you so much! You answer helped me to save state of selected cells!